# Should we bath after funeral?

Tags: rituals

Here in India we bath after funeral, But my prior question was "What is funeral law of Buddhism?" and  answerer said that when he lived in a forest monastery in Thailand, dead monks & residents were cremated on a pile of wood in the forest & they would practice meditation on the burning corpse. Therefor I think no need to bath but let me know should we bath after funeral?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buddhists usually cremate the bodies. But there's no Buddhist funeral law. You may or may not bath before, after or during the funeral if you see any health benefit to it.

Comment: @BonnWarapol Bath after funeral is proper, if bath make **wholesome** consciousness arise.

But bath after funeral is not proper, if bath make **unwholesome** consciousness arise.
Thanks again for invaluable answer and time

Answer (score 2):

Bath after funeral is proper, if bath make **wholesome** consciousness arise.

But bath after funeral is not proper, if bath make **unwholesome** consciousness arise.